# Escaping a full string in H2 insert statement

Tags: java, sql, insert, h2

I am trying to escape a whole string for insert into a longtext or varchar.  Basically I have a string full of all types of special characters and special words (ex. LIKE) and I just want to escape the whole thing so that I can insert it into my H2 database.

I've asked a few friends and they said that I should try serializing the data.  Is this the proper way to insert random strings into the db?  Should I be trying to do this with prepared statements?

Sorry I'm new to H2 and not that great with SQL.  Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for examples on how to use a `PreparedStatement`:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement#Examples
- http://www.jdbc-tutorial.com/jdbc-prepared-statements.htm

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I'll look into PreparedStatements for this, I appreciate the helpful links and your time!

Comment: I've set this up to use prepared statements as you guys suggested and it's working great.  This is saving me a ton of trouble thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `PreparedStatement` and pass the string as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer mark, I upvoted you but I'm going to accept thomas' answer since it had some helpful links for me to reference.  Thanks for the time!